# Need help processing opened images in ImageJ

Tags: macros, image-editing, code, image-processing, imagej

I've created a macro (based on different ones I've seen) that analyses particles areas in my picture, automatically copies the Area column in the results window to my clipboard and displays a window asking if I want to close every windows.

I would like to know if it is possible to apply this macro to pictures opened in ImageJ and get all the results (Area mostly) in a single results window. I can't use the batch processing feature because my folder contains sets of pictures that must be analyze separately from each other (different strains of microorganisms) in order to get the results for each strain separately.

Here is my macro at the moment, I know it is darn ugly but it works fairly well :

```
run("8-bit");
run("Threshold...");
waitForUser;
getThreshold(lower,upper);
if (lower==-1)
    exit("Threshold was not set");
run("Convert to Mask");
run("Fill Holes");
run("Set Scale...", "distance=2.87 known=1 unit=µm global");
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=30-Infinity display exclude add");
close();
closeWin("ROI Manager");
closeWin("Threshold");
closeWin("Log");
String.resetBuffer;
  for (i=0; i<nResults; i++)
      String.append(getResult("Area", i) + "\n");
  String.copy(String.buffer);
waitForUser("Work done", "WORK DONE: Close all windows?");
if (isOpen("Results")) {
         selectWindow("Results"); 
         run("Close" );

function closeWin(winName)
{
    if (isOpen(winName)) 
    {
        selectWindow(winName);
        run("Close");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to do it, here's the code if anyone is interested :

```
for (i=1; i<=nImages; i++) {
    selectImage(i);
    run("8-bit");
    run("Threshold...");
    waitForUser;
    getThreshold(lower,upper);
    if (lower==-1)
        exit("Threshold was not set");
    run("Convert to Mask");
    run("Fill Holes");
    run("Set Scale...", "distance=2.87 known=1 unit=µm global");
    run("Analyze Particles...", "size=30-Infinity display exclude add");
}
close("*");
closeWin("ROI Manager");
closeWin("Threshold");
closeWin("Log");
String.resetBuffer;
  for (i=0; i<nResults; i++)
      String.append(getResult("Area", i) + "\n");
  String.copy(String.buffer);
waitForUser("Work done", "WORK DONE: Close all windows?");
if (isOpen("Results")) {
         selectWindow("Results"); 
         run("Close" );

function closeWin(winName)
{
    if (isOpen(winName)) 
    {
        selectWindow(winName);
        run("Close");
    }
}
```